# How can I add an active class if any Option buttons are selected?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add active class to a Submit button provided any of the options from a button group is selected. For some reason I am not able to make it work.

https://jsfiddle.net/75ybncud

```js
$('#optionbutton1').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#submitbutton').prop('aria-disabled', false);
  $('#submitbutton').removeAttr('disabled');
  $('#submitbutton').addClass('active');
});

$('#optionbutton2').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#submitbutton').prop('aria-disabled', false);
  $('#submitbutton').removeAttr('disabled');
  $('#submitbutton').addClass('active');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="btn-group list-group" role="group" id="fabricList">
    <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="optionbutton1">
      <div class="row">
        <p class="font-weight-bold col-sm-2">Option 1</p>
      </div>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="optionbutton2">
      <div class="row">
        <p class="font-weight-bold col-sm-2">Option 2</p>
      </div>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="row my-4 mx-auto">
    <a class="btn btn-info mr-auto ml-3 disabled" href="#select-color" id="submitbutton">Submit</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @freedomn-m Apology for the confusion. I had corrected the duplicate id part later. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove class `disabled` using [`.removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) not attribute as it's a class on your button.

This is a class in bootstrap that disables the `<button>`/`<a>` tags:

```js
$('#optionbutton1').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#submitbutton').prop('aria-disabled', false);
  $('#submitbutton').removeClass('disabled');
  $('#submitbutton').addClass('active');
});

$('#optionbutton2').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#submitbutton').prop('aria-disabled', false);
  $('#submitbutton').removeClass('disabled');
  $('#submitbutton').addClass('active');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="btn-group list-group" role="group" id="fabricList">
    <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="optionbutton1">
      <div class="row">
        <p class="font-weight-bold col-sm-2">Option 1</p>
      </div>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="optionbutton2">
      <div class="row">
        <p class="font-weight-bold col-sm-2">Option 2</p>
      </div>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="row my-4 mx-auto">
    <a class="btn btn-info mr-auto ml-3 disabled" href="#select-color" id="submitbutton">Submit</a>
  </div>
</div>
```